# Returning bool from async method

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have to use a method as `async` and return as `Task<bool>`. But at the `await` keyword i am getting can not await string as error at compile time itself. I tried to return bool also from the method but in vain .Here is my method..

```
public async Task<bool> searchName(string Name)
{
    Group retrievedGroup = new Group();
    string foundGroup = null;
    try
    {
        foundGroup = await Client().Groups
                .Where(group => group.DisplayName.Equals(Name))
                .ExecuteAsync().Result.ToString();

         if (foundGroup == "Some Name")
         {
             return true;
         }
         else
         {
             return false;
         }
    }
    catch (){ }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is just operator priorities.
 Use parentheses. You should remove the `Result` Also.

```
foundGroup = (await Client().Groups
                .Where(group => group.DisplayName.Equals(Name))
                .ExecuteAsync()).ToString();
```

dot (`.`) has higher priority than await so when you have

```
foundGroup = await Client().Groups
        .Where(group => group.DisplayName.Equals(Name))
        .ExecuteAsync().Result.ToString();
```

it gonna await for `ToString();`. And also note that you have

```
ExecuteAsync().Result.ToString();
```

Accessing `Result` of a Task cause it to execute and you lose all asynchronous conditions you wanna achieve.

Comment: What do you mean till all get finished?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `Task.Result` with async-await as it will simply synchronously block on your method call. Instead, simply `await`:

```
public async Task<bool> SearchNameAsync(string Name)
{
    Group retrievedGroup = new Group();

    List<string> foundGroup = await Client().Groups
                                .Where(group => group.DisplayName.Equals(Name))
                                .ExecuteAsync();


    return foundGroup.Contains("Some Name", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

**Side note:**

1. Use the "Async" postfix on your async methods.
2. Do follow .NET naming conventions, which are PascalCase for methods.
3. Don't use empty `catch` block, they will make your life harder when you try to debug your code and don't understand why this method returns `false` instead of throwing. Or at least log something.
4. I used `string.Equals` instead of `==` as you may want to provide a `StringComparison` option, if, for example, you want to do a case insensitive search.

Comment: I need to return a bool ..Not a string

Comment: Why do you think this method returns a `string`?

Comment: @Lara Why are you awaiting a `string`? Where do yo do that exactly in my code?

Comment: ` string foundGroup = await` i am awaiting like this ..but getting error as said up at that line

Comment: @Lara Show me the complete line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99130/discussion-between-lara-and-yuval-itzchakov).